# PHP Code is not running on my Apache server

Tags: server, apache2, php

My PHP code is written as such:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

And is saved in /var/www/html/ as index.php

I am accessing it through 127.0.0.1/index.php

I have a completely clean install of Apache2, PHP7, and libapache2-mod-php7.0

When I access it on apache it shows nothing but a blank page as if nothing is being run. I have tested to make sure the module is loaded with a2enmod, and have confirmed it is.

Nothing on the forums has applied to me thus far, so I posted this.

Comment: did you restart apache ?

Comment: Go systematically. First try with an `.html` file. If it runs then you know  apache is working and the issue is with php only. Hence try this first.    With your given information we cannot say much.