# PHP code not showing on Apache 2.4

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have slight predicament with getting PHP to work on Apache. I have tried everything, restarting the service, reeinstaling php, and apache, but to no avail. There is already a similair question to mine on the site, but there is no answer provided: [PHP Code is not running on my Apache server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861702/php-code-is-not-running-on-my-apache-server)

If anyone has any idea on how to fix it, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the php modules for apache, and did you follow the suggestions in the comments?

Comment: I just returned to the page to delete the question, yup, i fixed it. :) Installed all the modules and now it works. Thanks for the comment nonetheless :)